# Slow query on counting items

Tags: mysql

I have a list with filters and I have to count how many items are in each one filter, but the following query gets slower and much slower when multiple filters are set

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT itf.`filter_id`
    FROM `item_to_filter` AS `itf`
    JOIN `item_to_inventory` AS `iti` ON (itf.`item_id` = iti.`item_id` AND iti.`quantity` > 0)
    WHERE 1 = 1
    AND (
        (itf.`filter_group_id` = 2 AND itf.`filter_id` IN (1))
        OR (itf.`filter_group_id` = 4 AND itf.`filter_id` IN (55)) //gets slower
        OR (itf.`filter_group_id` = 1 AND itf.`filter_id` IN (107, 108)) //gets much slower
    )
    GROUP BY itf.`item_id`
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT itf.`filter_group_id`) = 3
) AS `total_items`
```

Is there any other way to write the query to count items from each filter

Here you can see the tables structure and data (are the indexes correctly sets?)

[image]
[image]

Comment: OR conditions can be optimized with UNION ALL. But first I would try to add a redundant condition `itf.filter_group_id IN (1,2,4)` or (might even be more selective) `itf.filter_id IN (1,55,107,108)`. It's also possible that MySQL can optimize the OR conditions if you had an index on `item_to_filter(filter_group_id, filter_id)`.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Thank you for your answer. I'll try to optimize how you said. but I think something is wrong with JOIN statement. If I remove the JOIN `item_to_inventory` the query is 3x faster.

Comment: Try a `STRAIGHT_JOIN`.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel hmm still the same execution time

Comment: @PaulSpiegel can you show an example how can I optimize with UNION ALL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one: Wrap the conditions into a UNION ALL subquery. Then join it with your tables.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT itf.filter_id
    FROM (
        SELECT 2 as filter_group_id 1   as filter_id UNION ALL
        SELECT 4 as filter_group_id 55  as filter_id UNION ALL
        SELECT 1 as filter_group_id 107 as filter_id UNION ALL
        SELECT 1 as filter_group_id 108 as filter_id
    ) f -- filters
    JOIN item_to_filter AS itf USING(filter_group_id, filter_id)
    JOIN item_to_inventory AS iti ON itf.item_id = iti.item_id
    WHERE iti.quantity > 0
    GROUP BY itf.item_id
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT itf.filter_group_id) = 3
) AS total_items
```

You should define an index on `item_to_filter(filter_group_id, filter_id)`. But as I wrote in the comment, it's possible that the engine can do the same optimization if that index is present.

To make a better use of the given indexes you could rewrite your query to

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT item_id
    FROM item_to_inventory AS iti
    JOIN item_to_filter AS itf2 USING(item_id) -- itf2: group_id = 2
    JOIN item_to_filter AS itf4 USING(item_id) -- itf4: group_id = 4
    JOIN item_to_filter AS itf1 USING(item_id) -- itf1: group_id = 1
    WHERE iti.quantity > 0
      AND itf2.filter_group_id = 2 AND itf2.filter_id IN (1)
      AND itf4.filter_group_id = 4 AND itf4.filter_id IN (55)
      AND itf1.filter_group_id = 1 AND itf1.filter_id IN (107,108)
) AS total_items
```

But even here an index on `item_to_filter(filter_group_id, filter_id)` should improve the performance.

Comment: I appreciate your answer! You saved me from hell. The second query has a great performance with almost x5 speed. Thank you very much!